# PHP calling index of an array with define constant

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I have some problem with referencing a define constant to access array:

```
    define('NAME_INDEX', 0);
    ...
    if( $file ) {
        while( ($line = fgets($file))!==false ) {
            $array = explode(" , ", $line);
            echo "<br>$array[NAME_INDEX]<br>";
        }
    }
```

The error that I received:

```
Notice: Undefined index: NAME_INDEX
```

It prints out the value that I want when I do `echo $array[0]` though. Might anyone know what went wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show us your entire/full/real code and the exact error message

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure the error occurs there?

Comment: You don't have quotes around it do you? `$array['NAME_INDEX']` won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my full code. Instead of showing the value that I want which is the name, it returns me the Notice message as stated in my question. I'm not sure what went wrong.

Comment: `"<br>".$array[NAME_INDEX]."<br>"` or `"<br>{$array[NAME_INDEX]}<br>";`

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley Not related, since PHP does parse variables when surrounded by the correct syntactic sugar, as in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
echo "<br>$array[NAME_INDEX]<br>";
```

to:

```
echo "<br>" . $array[NAME_INDEX] . "<br>"; //OR echo "<br>{$array[NAME_INDEX]}<br>";
```

You can read more about concatenation in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it would work because `$array[0]` works. 'Will accept the answer in 3 min.